# Change direction for an animation

Tags: css, animation, sprite

I have drawn an animation using a spritesheet with this code. The animation is a ball which bounces from left to right, I would like to get some help on how I could rotate the animation making it bounce from top to bottom. Any ideas?

```
<style>
    #ball{
    background: url(bilder/ball_bounce.png);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    -webkit-animation: ball-bounce 0.5s steps(6) infinite;
    animation: ball-bounce 0.7s steps(6) infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes ball-bounce {
    from{background-position: 0px;}
    to{background-position: -300px;}
    }

    @keyframes ball-bounce {
    from{background-position: 0px;}
    to{background-position: -300px;}
    }

</style>
<div id="ball"></div>
```

Comment: If the animation is drawn, can't you just use `transform: rotateX(90deg)` to turn it on its side?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `background-position` `y` axis instead of `x` axis:

```
@-webkit-keyframes ball-bounce {
    from{background-position: 0px 0px;}
    to{background-position: 0px -300px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's working from left to right, then just use rotation to make it bounce from top to bottom:

```
#ball {
    /* Use rotateX to rotate around the divs anchor point (default is center center) - could also be -90deg depending on how it looks. */
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

Heres a little snippet with the same basic idea, just not using `background-image`s and `background-position`s to do it, it shows how you can rotate it without affecting anything else.

```css
body > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: whiteSmoke;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {left: 5%;}
  50% {left: 90%;}
  100% {left: 5%;}
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0% {left: 5%;}
  50% {left: 90%;}
  100% {left: 5%;}
}

body > div > div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2000ms ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: bounce 2000ms ease-in-out infinite;
}
body > div + div {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div><div></div></div>

<div><div></div></div>
```